# Unable to create a file in external storage USB?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have been working on a project where I have to store a text file on an external USB connected to android device. I have given READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in my manifest file. Here is what I have done.

```
 boolean Available= false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
        // Both Read and write operations available
        Available= true;
    } else {
        // SD card not mounted
        Available = false;
    }
    if(Available) {


        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +     
    "/file");
        if (!f.exists())
            if (!f.mkdir()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, myfolder + " can't be created.", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else
                Toast.makeText(this, myfolder + " can be created.", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I have checked for the device to be inserted or not after that I have tried to get path by calling Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). But when I create a new file it always gives me answer unable to create directory. Please anyone could help me with this.

Comment: I have tried both .mkdir() and mkdirs(). I want to save a file in usb but problem is that it throws exception of file not found.

Comment: You should show the exception's stack trace in the question too.

Comment: Their is no exception in this toast is called every time saying folder can't be created.

Comment: You said in the previous comment: "throws exception of file not found", you should catch that exception and update the question with it.

Comment: have you set up file provider?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the stack trace error that you mentioned in your comment, but if you grant the permission in the settings your code should work.

[image: Grant permission]

Probably the best thing is to check for the permission and only if available procede with the storage logic, something like:

```
boolean Available = false;
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Grant the external storage permission first!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } else {
   // then do your rest of the storage checks and logic.
 }
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) more details on how to handle the permission request.

Also note, that you should probably need to use the folder that you declared, so instead of:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +     
    "/file");
```

you should use:

```
File f = new File(myfolder, "file");
```

Comment: I have checked for permission it goes into the else part which means that I have already given permission in onCreate Method and manifest file.                                 The problem is when I create a file directory i.e(file.mkdirs())  it always fails to create a file and thus I am not able to perform further operations of writing a file.

Answer (score 0):

Along with answer provided by @Dan to add runtime permissions to your code, You also need to set up file provider for versions android 7.0 and above. You need to add following changes.

Add this in `manifest.xml`

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.yourappname.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/my_paths" />
</provider>
```

create `my_paths.xml` in `res/xml/` folder :

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing) for further info.

Comment: do I have to provide the path of external file my_paths in my directory myfolder in File f = new File(myfolder, "file"); Do I have to save data in my_paths and then transfer it to the external usb???

Comment: check documentation it has different paths for different case.